# WCF Security - how to allow all callers to this url?

Tags: wcf, security, ssl, authorization

I have a WCF service self-hosted in a windows service environment that works fine over http; over https I am unable to get to one URL without seeing the windows login prompt when running the silverlight application (or just opening the page in IE). I am using the IPolicyRetriever interface to ensure that the ClientAccessPolicy.xml file is found for the Silverlight app. This is working correctly.

The service in question has two endpoints defined:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="defaultBehavior" name="WCFServices.Scheduler">
<endpoint address="WCFServices/Scheduler/" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="dBinding" contract="WCFServices.IScheduler" />
<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFServices.IPolicyRetriever" behaviorConfiguration="PolicyBehavior" bindingConfiguration="dBinding" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://myservername.org/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

If I go to the `https://myservername.org/` I see the test service frontend (with a link to the wsdl). This is exposing the root IPolicyRetriever instance that the Silverlight app uses to pull down the policy file. I can load this and other URLs that expose the WCF service without any login prompts. BUT if I go to `https://myservername.org/WCFServices/Scheduler/` in IE 8 I am greeted with a windows login. If I reset the security settings on the service and client to use http, I am able to do go to the latter url without the login prompt, and the silverlight app functions as expected. I suspect it has something to do with this WCF service being the only one with two endpoints defined (this windows service hosts 5 other WCF services, all of which only have 1 endpoint defined). Am I missing some authorization rules? I don't understand how that can be because all the other services load without prompts.

I would appreciate any help. I need the full `https://myservername.org/WCFServices/Scheduler/` to serve the WCF service without asking for a login. Thanks for taking the time to read this.

As far as security, I only have this as my binding:

```
<binding name="dBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600">
      <security mode="Transport">
      </security>
    </binding>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by adding these lines to my security binding:

```
<security mode="Transport">
   <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"/>
</security>
```

...but that led to a host of other issues, all of which I've been able to handle thanks to WCF logging. If you run into a NOT FOUND (400) error when debugging your WCF service, don't believe it. Turn on server side debugging and pour through the generated log files -- you'll get to the bottom of it.

I should also note that I've found the second endpoint to return a bad request (400) when opening in a web browser, and this is BY DESIGN. The first endpoint will list all additional endpoints in its wsdl, and you can still use any of them in a proxy generating tool. Don't worry if you're getting a bad request error when trying to access them directly in a browser.